# ASP MVC 5 Client Validation of enumeration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to check an enumeration field in a form. The field is Required. Here is how I defined the enumeration:

```
public enum Categories
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3
}
```

and the property of my ViewModel:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "It is mandatory!")]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(Categories), ErrorMessage="Unknown category")]
    [DisplayName("Category A")]
    public Categories Category { get; set; }
```

I want to validate this on the client side. But at the beginning, when I try to create an object with Category, the category value is 0 (the EditTemplate for Category is a Combobox). It means, I should get the message "It is mandatory!", isn't it? But I don't get any message that say Field Category is mandatory. I cannot understand how the RequiredAttribute works with Enumeration fields.

Comment: You need to show how you generate the control, but make the property nullable `public Categories? Category { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

An `enum` is a value type not a reference type. `Required` checks for null, and you only get nulls with a reference type.

You may try:

```
public class Categories { }
```

Comment: Why not public Categories? Category { get; set; } ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanation. Finally I used the solution Nullable<Categories>. I want that Categories remains enum